# .NET Problem Works just fine on one computer on another there's stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, overflow

I wrote a simple C# program using some graphic functions as drawElipse and drawLine at System.Drawing.Graphics. It works perfectly on one computer, but at my laptop it gives overflow exception at the graphics functions. I need the program to work on the laptop for a presentation after five hours, please help me.

Here are the two functions I get the error in:

```
private void drawDot(int n)
{
    Graphics gfx = CreateGraphics();
    int mapx = (int)verts[n].mapx;
    int mapy = (int)verts[n].mapy;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen, 5);
    if (mapx > 2 && mapy > 2)
    {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)mapy - 2, (int)mapx - 2, 10, 10);
        gfx.DrawEllipse(myPen, rect);
    }

}

private void drawLine(int n, int k)
{
    int mapnx = (int)verts[n].mapx;
    int mapny = (int)verts[n].mapy;
    int mapkx = (int)verts[k].mapx;
    int mapky = (int)verts[k].mapy;
    Graphics gfx = CreateGraphics();
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen, 3);
    gfx.DrawLine(myPen, mapny, mapnx, mapky, mapkx);
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code??

Comment: does your laptop have less memory than the computer it works on?   ....

Comment: Voting to close, without code there is no real question.

Comment: I agree this is too vague a question.

Comment: I had a similar issue about a year ago - turned out to be a buggy video driver.  Try updating on the problematic machine.

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicitly dispose the `Graphics` object in the method you have called. You can do this in two different ways.

1. Explicitly call `gfx.Dispose()` at the end of your methods.
2. Wrap the code that accesses `gfx` in `using`, like this:

   ```
   using (Graphics gfx = CreateGraphics())
   {
       // call gfx methods liek DrawLine()
   }
   ```

You can read a bit more in the MSDN documentation for the [`CreateGraphics()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method.

Comment: Note that Pen is IDisposable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is related to one machine JITing to x64, while the other machine JITs to x86.

Comment: If that's the problem, how to fix it?